# How to make jOOQ generate composite foreign keys not referencing a primary key?

Tags: java, h2, jooq

Using the latest jOOQ with H2 1.4.194 no foreign keys in `Keys.java` are generated for the following (reduced) schema:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a INT, b INT, PRIMARY KEY (a));
CREATE TABLE u (a INT, b INT, FOREIGN KEY (a,b) REFERENCES t (a,b));
```

Adding a unique constraint as follows doesn't help:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a INT, b INT, PRIMARY KEY (a), UNIQUE (a,b));
CREATE TABLE u (a INT, b INT, FOREIGN KEY (a,b) REFERENCES t (a,b));
```

Changing the FK to reference the primary key (whether simple or composite) makes the FK appear.

Querying the FK via H2 works as expected.

Doesn't look like a regression (tried various 3.x jOOQ's), so wondering if I'm doing something wrong. Generator config (via maven plugin) as follows:

```
<name>org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator</name>
<database>
    <name>org.jooq.util.h2.H2Database</name>
    <includes>.*</includes>
    <excludes />
    <inputSchema>PUBLIC</inputSchema>
</database>
```

Comment: Do you have a unique constraint or index on `t(a, b)`? It should work with a constraint, but perhaps not with an index

Comment: I actually had a unique constraint in my non-reduced example - doesn't help. Interestingly, the constraint itself gets generated as `createUniqueKey(T.T, "X", T.T.A);` -- should be `createUniqueKey(T.T, "X", T.T.A, T.T.B);`, right? Again, this is correct in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Perhaps, for completeness' sake, could you update your question with the exact unique constraint? I think this is a bug. Will investigate soon and give you an answer, then.

Comment: Hmm, interesting update. May I ask: What's the reason why your primary key doesn't include `b`?

Comment: I'm modelling polymorphism with a "type marker", `(a,b)` are really `(id, type)`. Accounts are either users or organizations and, crucially, they share an id namespace, so 'wibble' can't be both a user and an org. A plausible bunch of tuples would look like this: account: {('foo', 'u'), ('bar', 'u'), ('baz', 'o')}; user: {('foo', 'u'), ('bar', 'u')}; org: {('baz', 'o')}. All tables obviously have other columns as well.

Comment: Yes, but why not make that the primary key, then? If you're using `(id, type)` foreign key references...?

Comment: Very good point, yes, I can do that. Some of my tables only care about users, not orgs - in these cases my FKs reference just `(id)`, not `(id, type)`. I was under the misapprehension that cascading deletes referencing non-PKs wouldn't be allowed. However, that's clearly wrong, so I'm saved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Working around missing foreign keys

Starting from jOOQ 3.14, if you're missing foreign keys from generated output either because of a limitation in jOOQ, or because you don't actually have any foreign keys in your schema, or because you're generating views, you can create [synthetic objects](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-synthetic-objects/), including [synthetic primary keys](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-synthetic-objects/codegen-database-synthetic-pks/), [synthetic unique keys](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-synthetic-objects/codegen-database-synthetic-uks/), and reference them from [synthetic foreign keys](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-synthetic-objects/codegen-database-synthetic-fks/) with a configuration like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <syntheticObjects>
        <foreignKeys>
          <foreignKey>
            <tables>U</tables>
            <fields>
              <field>A</field>
              <field>B</field>
            </fields>
            <referencedTable>T</referencedTable>
            <referencedFields>
              <field>A</field>
              <field>B</field>
            </referencedFields>
          </foreignKey>
        </foreignKeys>
      </syntheticObjects>
    </database>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

There are different ways to configure this, e.g. by name reference or by column reference, etc. [check out the manual for details](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-synthetic-objects/codegen-database-synthetic-fks/).

#### Historic answer (it was a bug)

The query that is run internally by jOOQ's code generator is this:

```
select 
  "CROSS_REFERENCES"."FK_NAME", 
  "CROSS_REFERENCES"."FKTABLE_NAME", 
  "CROSS_REFERENCES"."FKTABLE_SCHEMA", 
  "CROSS_REFERENCES"."FKCOLUMN_NAME", 
  "CONSTRAINTS"."CONSTRAINT_NAME", 
  "CONSTRAINTS"."CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA"
from "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."CROSS_REFERENCES"
  join "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."CONSTRAINTS"
  on (
    "CROSS_REFERENCES"."PK_NAME" = "CONSTRAINTS"."UNIQUE_INDEX_NAME"
    and "CROSS_REFERENCES"."PKTABLE_NAME" = "CONSTRAINTS"."TABLE_NAME"
    and "CROSS_REFERENCES"."PKTABLE_SCHEMA" = "CONSTRAINTS"."TABLE_SCHEMA"
  )
where (
  "CROSS_REFERENCES"."FKTABLE_SCHEMA" in (
    'PUBLIC'
  )
  and "CONSTRAINTS"."CONSTRAINT_TYPE" in (
    'PRIMARY KEY', 'UNIQUE'
  )
)
order by 
  "CROSS_REFERENCES"."FKTABLE_SCHEMA" asc, 
  "CROSS_REFERENCES"."FK_NAME" asc, 
  "CROSS_REFERENCES"."ORDINAL_POSITION" asc
```

The query appears correct, but there seems to be a misunderstanding in how H2 encodes unique constraints in these dictionary views. Or a bug in H2.

I've created two issues, let's see which one is right:

- Bug in H2: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/466
- Bug in jOOQ: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5972